# Filtering with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, orm

I am new to ORM's and trying to query a table with a timestamp column. My results however are empty and understandably so since I am querying a timestamp field with a date. I read and found out I can use 'sqlalchemy.sql import func' but my filter is dynamically created based on query params so I was wondering how to go about it.

Code for query model:

```
def merch_trans_sum_daily_summaries(db_engine, query_params):
    query_filters = get_filters(query_params)
    page, limit, filters = query_filters.page, query_filters.limit, query_filters.filters
    strict_limit = query_filters.strict_limit
    
    with Session(db_engine) as sess:
        results = paginate(sess.query(MerchTransSumDaily)
                           .filter_by(**filters).yield_per(1000),
                           page, limit, strict_limit)
    metadata = results.metadata
    query_data = results.data
    if not query_data:
        raise exc.NoResultFound
    data = [record._asdict() for record in query_data]
    return data, metadata
```

Here is my get_filters function

```
def get_filters(query_parameters, strict_limit=100, default_page=1):
    if query_parameters and "batch_type" in query_parameters:
        query_parameters.pop('batch_type')
    limit = int(query_parameters["limit"]) if query_parameters and "limit" in query_parameters else strict_limit
    page = int(query_parameters["page"]) if query_parameters and "page" in query_parameters else default_page

    filters = ""
    if query_parameters:
        filters = {key_: value_ for key_, value_ in query_parameters.items() if key_ not in ["page", "limit", "paginate", "filter"]}
    return QueryFilters(limit, page, filters, strict_limit)
```

Comment: There's no easy way to make this code handle querying timestamps with dates.  A better approach might be to convert your date to a timestamp prior to querying.

Comment: True but records come in at different times of the day. Wouldn't doing that limit the query to a particular timestamp instead of the date?

Comment: Convert the date - say `2022-01-01` to the earliest suitable time on the date - `2022-01-01 00:00:00` - and find timestamps greater than that?.